# How do i get concurrent asp.net on linux?

Tags: linux, concurrency, mono

-edit2- It turns out asp.net (i dont know if its mono specific) blocks if the url and ip address are the same. Its nonblocking if i run it from my local machine and server at the same time.

I have nginx setup using mono's fastcgi server (fastcgi-mono-server2.exe) on debian linux.

Below is a sample of my config file. I modified the page to sleep for 5seconds and opened up two tabs and visited the page. The 2nd took 10seconds to load (the first waits for 5seconds, loaded while i was looking at the 2nd page which then loaded 5seconds later)

How do i get concurrent request on the same website?
-edit- it seems to be concurrent across different domains/app since my other pages load while that test page blocks however the test pages are serial. I would like all pages on all domains concurrent.

```
server {
    server_name    box.com;

    root /var/www/WebApplication1/WebApplication1;
    index Default.aspx default.aspx;

    location ~ \.(aspx|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|dll)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/srv/mono/monoserve.pid;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about mono asp.net, try disabling cookies when testing. It might be your application is locking session storage to keep things serial, thus consistent, per-user. Without cookies (also across domains), your tabs get unique sessions each.